# Can you combine MySQL with MYSQLI in different pages?

Tags: php

I've found out here it's not possible to combine mysql and mysqli commands side by side. What about having them in different pages of the same project?

Comment: Each page operates independently, they don't affect each other. But you shouldn't use `mysql` at all any more. It was deprecated years ago, and removed entirely in PHP 7.

Comment: Sure, you can use them both in the same file if you're feeling adventurous. As long as you keep track of which query uses which API. A result from a `mysql_query()` can *only* be processed using `mysql_` functions, while a result from a `mysqli_query()` can *only* be processed using `mysqli_` functions. Don't mix *that* up and you should be fine.